# Create LabeledPoint from sparse vector in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I created a feature vector in a DataFrame in spark/scala using the VectorAssembler. So far everything works fine. Now I want to create LabeledPoints from the label and the sparse vector.

```
val labeledPoints = featureDf.map{r=>
  val label = r(0).toString.toDouble + r(1).toString.toDouble + r(2).toString.toDouble
  val features = r(r.size-1)
  LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.sparse(features))

}
```

But that doesn't work. I get a compile error. The error is:

```
overloaded method value sparse with alternatives:
(size: Int,elements: Iterable[(Integer,java.lang.Double)])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
<and>
(size: Int,elements: Seq[(Int, scala.Double)])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
<and>
(size: Int,indices: Array[Int],values:Array[scala.Double])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
cannot be applied to (Any)
```

I already tried to cast the vector with `val features = r(r.size-1).asInstanceOf[Vector]` and so on but nothing works. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is `Row.getAs` method:

```
val features = r.getAs[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector](r.size - 1)
```

It also supports extracting by name so assuming your column is called `features`:

```
r.getAs[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector]("features")
```